# Error shown while inserting the elements in to table

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm creating the table with following query

```
CREATE TABLE LSP_Schedule(
lab_Id VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
test_code VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
test_date DATE NOT NULL,
slot_time VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
duration NUMBER(3) NOT NULL CHECK (duration IN (30,60,90,120)),
status VARCHAR2(20) CHECK (status IN ('booked','Free')),
PRIMARY KEY (lab_Id,test_code)

)
```

and to insert the date into this table is write the query as follows

```
INSERT INTO LSP_SCHEDULE VALUES('1000','1001','2010-07-12','10:00AM-10:30AM',30,'booked')
```

but it shows the error as

```
ORA-01861:literal does not match format string
```

can you give the correction for the above query to insert the data successfully.
i'm using `SqlDbx version 3.51.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

```
INSERT INTO LSP_SCHEDULE VALUES
      ('1000','1001', TO_DATE('2010-07-12', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),'10:00AM-10:30AM',30,'booked');
```

I guess u have to convert it to date format.

Comment: This Query "INSERT INTO LSP_SCHEDULE VALUES('1000','1001',to_date('2010-07-12','yyyy-mm-dd'),'10:00AM-10:30AM',30,'booked')" giving date along with time as 12:00:00AM but i want only date not time

Comment: You can use `trunc` function. Try this `trunc(TO_DATE('2010-07-12', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI'))`

Comment: again above query displaying time but i want only date

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the string literal for date '2010-07-12' with TO_DATE('2010-07-12','YYYY-MM-DD')

Comment: This Query "INSERT INTO LSP_SCHEDULE VALUES('1000','1001',to_date('2010-07-12','yyyy-mm-dd'),'10:00AM-10:30AM',30,'booked')" giving date along with time as 12:00:00AM but i want only date not time